# SpringBoot controller returns XML although content-type set to JSON explicitly

Tags: spring-boot, content-type, spring-rest

I have 2 spring boot REST-services which interact as producer and consumer.
One is producer of JSON content and the other is the consumer.

In the consumer service I use Spring's `RestTemplate` to invoke the producer's endpoint and get the result.

#### Code

Producer's relevant code for controller's POST endpoint is as follows:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/cars", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Cars> getCars(/* methods params */) {
    // some code here
    HttpHeaders respHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    respHeader.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    ResponseEntity<Cars> resp = new ResponseEntity<Cars>(cars, respHeader, HttpStatus.OK);
    
    return resp;
}
```

Notice in the producer code above:

- I don't have `produces="application/json"` specified explicitly in the `RequestMapping` annotation.
- However, I set content-type as "application/json" in the response headers.

#### Issue

But consumer gets the response in XML instead of JSON.
Jackson is there in the class path.

#### Questions

What explains returning XML and not JSON even though content-type explicitly set in response-headers to "application/json"?

Assume the response-header doesn't have any effect, what is the default - is it XML instead of JSON?

Comment: Try removing HttpHeaders respHeader = new HttpHeaders();
   respHeader.set("Content-Type", "application/json");

Comment: By default it return json so needn't to mention that in header

Comment: my question is, why does it return xml the way I have coded it ? I did put produces="applicaiton/json" and it returned json.

Comment: Can you share the request and response (including headers) with us?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the order of HttpMessageConverters matters. I encountered the same problem with default xml responses when there is a transitive xml dependency. Adding MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to the top of converters list solved it for me.

For some reason `configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` this suggestion from previous answers breaks apis that produce media types other than json (when requests does not contain `Accept` header). These apis started returning http status 406 with json as the defaultContentType

My Spring Boot version is 2.7.1

Here is the configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Override
  public void extendMessageConverters(@NotNull List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(0, new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper));
  }

}
```

When there is no default content type defined, xml becomes the default since spring iterates over converters to decide produceable content types. And since xml converter is added before json converter it uses xml. Adding json converter ahead of xml converter fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the default content-type for any response by customizing Spring's [`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833181/when-to-implement-webmvcconfigurer-to-configure-spring-mvc#56833574).

To do so add following code to a given configuration class that is annotated with `@Configuration`:

```java
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer customConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a breakpoint in Spring's [`ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter.html) and debug to see the resolved message-converter for your response.

#### Content Negotiation

The concept and process between a web-client and -server determining the content-type of a response is called [Content-Negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation).

Since [Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) the registered `WebMvcConfigurer` and `HttpMessageConverters` are responsible for the representation and content-type of the response.

In SpringBoot those are autoconfigured.

For any `@RestController` or a controller-endpoint having `@ResponseBody` the default content-type of the response is XML, if Jackson is available in the classpath and auto-configured successfully, the default content-type should be JSON.

See also:

- tutorial on Baeldung: [Spring MVC Content Negotiation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml)
- [How to make spring boot default to application/json;charset=utf-8 instead of application/json;charset=iso-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640629/how-to-make-spring-boot-default-to-application-jsoncharset-utf-8-instead-of-app)